# Поле ввода импута

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Как в поле ввода импута получить(если это возможно) :

1. одну часть текста сделать одним
       шрифтом
2. второю часть другим
           шрифтом

http://fotki.yandex.ru/users/soledar1984/view/787001/?page=0 (пример то что должно получиться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставить в поле `input` первую часть текста, растянуть `input` до необходимой ширины, затем простой `div` с жесткими параметрами `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;` со второй частью вашего текста расположить в коде под `input`'ом, таким образом он отобразится сверху в правом углу поля `input`. Это легко делается, обернув и `input` и `div` во внешний `div` с атрибутами `position: relative;`. Input'у задайте один шрифт, а внутреннему div'у - другой. Как-то так.